# Not able to select the right element while automating makemytrip website

Tags: java, selenium

I am trying to automate mmt website where in i am trying to automate the From textbox.
Its an auto suggestive text box where in the cities will come automatically when you start typing.
The problem is i am not able to click that element once i start typing.
Because of this my assertion is also failing.
Can you please solve the problem.
Also is there any elegant way to do this task.

```
public void TC002_EnterFromCity() throws InterruptedException {
    By from_city_label = By.xpath("//div[@class='fsw_inputBox searchCity inactiveWidget ']/label");
    waitforelement(15, from_city_label);
    driver.findElement(from_city_label).click();
    By from_city_autotext = By.xpath("//div[@class='hsw_autocomplePopup autoSuggestPlugin ']/div/input");
    waitforelement(15, from_city_autotext);
    driver.findElement(from_city_autotext).sendKeys("De");
    Thread.sleep(5000);
    List<WebElement> Listofitems = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//p[@class='font14 appendBottom5 blackText']"));
        for(WebElement list:Listofitems)
        {
            String text=list.getText();
            Thread.sleep(1000);
            if (text.equalsIgnoreCase("Dehradun"))
            {
                list.sendKeys(Keys.ARROW_DOWN);
                list.sendKeys(Keys.ENTER);
                break;
            }


        }


       }
  @Test
public void assert_FromCity()
{
    WebElement lbl_fromcity=driver.findElement(By.id("fromCity"));
    String actual_text=lbl_fromcity.getAttribute("value");
    String expected_text="Dehradun";
    Assert.assertEquals(actual_text,expected_text);

}
```

Comment: can you share a link to that page?

Comment: U can navigate to makemytrip.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To select the desired element you do not have to use arrow down and enter keys.
Just click on that element.

```
public void TC002_EnterFromCity() throws InterruptedException {
    By from_city_label = By.xpath("//div[@class='fsw_inputBox searchCity inactiveWidget ']/label");
    waitforelement(15, from_city_label);
    driver.findElement(from_city_label).click();
    By from_city_autotext = By.xpath("//div[@class='hsw_autocomplePopup autoSuggestPlugin ']/div/input");
    waitforelement(15, from_city_autotext);
    driver.findElement(from_city_autotext).sendKeys("De");
    Thread.sleep(5000);
    List<WebElement> Listofitems = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//p[@class='font14 appendBottom5 blackText']"));
        for(WebElement list:Listofitems)
        {
            String text=list.getText();
            Thread.sleep(1000);
            if (text.equalsIgnoreCase("Dehradun"))
            {
                list.click();
                break;
            }

        }
   }
```